# string.Format did not work for string line type parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to pass two parameters to CallSome()

```
string.Format("CallSome({0},'{1}');", someId, someName);
```

But someName did not work for this kind of values which is having space. like

Its working for  '123', 'name'

But not for this 'My Name' Its given an error of this After 'My

Comment: are you pasting the code for `CallSome()` function?

Comment: impossible, unless we are dealing with an apostrophe...

Comment: Your javascript looks like C#, I guess you are missing a tag. Is that going to eval? The legend says it is evil.

Comment: It won't work if `someName` has a new line symbol or an apostrophe itself. In such case you would need to develop some escaping of `someName` before code goes into JS.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

> string.Format("CallSome({0},''{1}'');", someId, someName);

You need to *escape single quote* by *putting extra single quote in start and end*.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using C# and you want to output this to a web response in ASP.NET or similar web technology, then... your code should work.

For example, given `someId` = 123 and `someName` = "word, word":

```
CallSome(123,'word, word');
```

Just, check the output code you are getting in the web page, it will reveal the truth.

---

**Unless it is being inserted in a place where it is surrounded by single quotes.**

For example, given `someId` = 123 and `someName` = "word, word":

```
var something = 'CallSome(123, 'word, word')';
```

So, the first single quotes looks like the end of the text as far as the browser is concerned. In that case, you should use double quotes, like this:

```
var something = "CallSome(123, 'word, word')";
```

or this:

```
var something = 'CallSome(123, "word, word")';
```

Alternatively, you can escape your single quotes:

```
var something = 'CallSome(123, \'word, word\')';
```

---

**Unless it has quotes in the argument.**

For example, given `someId` = 123 and `someName` = "word' word":

```
var something = 'CallSome(123, 'word' word')';
```

Again, the first single quotes looks like the end of the text as far as the browser is concerned. That case is a bit more complicated, because it requires to escape quotes one way:

```
var something = "CallSome(123, 'word\' word')";
```

Or another:

```
var something = 'CallSome(123, "word\' word")';
```

---

**Unless it has a new line, a javascript comment, or I don't know what else in the argument.**

Just don't have those!

---

Now, in C# you Need to escape your quotes. To output double quotes you can do this:

```
string.Format("CallSome({0},\"{1}\");", someId, someName);
```

That gives:

```
CallSome(123,"word, word");
```

On the other hand, if you really need to use single quotes (I don't think so, given the bug), then you will have to escape them in the output javascript:

```
string.Format("CallSome({0},\\'{1}\\');", someId, someName);
```

That gives:

```
CallSome(123, \'word, word\');
```

Which is ok in if it is part of a quoted string, as my examples above:

```
var something = 'CallSome(123, \'word, word\')';
```